# Passing values from Servlet to my JSP

Tags: java, jsp, servlets

I need to pass the String value h from Servlet to the jsp page. If login is success it will be redirected to success page else it need to display "Invalid login message" in login.jsp page

```
    if(success)
    {
        RequestDispatcher view=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Success.html");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        String h="Invalid Login";
        RequestDispatcher view=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
        view.forward(request, response);
    }
```

I tried a lot, but its not working.

Comment: You tried "a lot"? Like what did you try? Did you try setting it as a request attribute? That's the standard approach.

Comment: yeah i tried in .jsp page as <%=request.getAttribute("h")%>.. am i wrong..?

Comment: yes, you are wrong, because you didn't set any attribute named "h". see the answer bellow!

Comment: you can also use the session to store information on... `reguest.getSession().setAttribute("Attribute","Value");` and in jsp use `value = session.getAttribute("Attribute").toString();`

Comment: As a side note, related to your `<%=request.getAttribute("h")%>`. Read here: [The use of scriptlets is highly discouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3180202/814702)

Comment: Servlet: boolean success=s.Login(d);
if(success){
RequestDispatcher view=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Success.html");
view.forward(request, response);
}
else
{
message="Invalid Password";
request.setAttribute("message", message);
RequestDispatcher view=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
view.forward(request, response);
} Jsp: <%=request.getAttribute("message")%> ... Its showing null at the jsp before clicking submit button and i need to clear this null.. Help pls

Answer (score 2):

Your else block will be like bellow:

```
else
{
   String h="Invalid Login";
   request.setAttibute("message",h);
   RequestDispatcher view=getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher("/Login.jsp");
   view.forward(request, response);
}
```

And in your `Login.jsp` file you should use:

```
${message}  //(El expression to access value)
```

And your message will be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

Try to store your data in some scope

In servlet

```
   request.setAttribute("Data", h);
```

in jsp

```
request.getAttribute("Data")
```

Answer (score 0):

You can store your data either in request or in session.Then access that value from your jsp page by using sessionScope or simply ${data}.

You can set values in request or session by using the code below in your Servlet.

```
request.setAttribute("data",h);
request.getSession.setAttribute("data",h);
```

In order to access this value in your jsp page. Add the below code in your jsp page

```
${data} //if you are storing data in request
${sessionScope.data} //If you are storing data in Session
```